# Remote connect to mysql server [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, my.cnf

I manage a file sharing website (like mediafire,hotFile, etc.) and there is a problem when people try to download from one of the servers.

It goes like this: I have one main server - there I have the mysql database and the website himself, and I have more servers to host the files.

The download process goes like this: user get a link to the outside server. This page connect remotely to the main server and make querys with the database. After the querys, the download get started.

Now, all of the downloads works fine, except from one of the servers. The weirdest thing is that sometimes the download from this server is works, and sometimes not!

It's about 70% of times the download from the problematic server is works, and 30% of times the download isn't works.

When the download isn't working the error message is:

```
Connect failed: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
```

The `my.cnf` looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
concurrent_insert = 2
connect_timeout = 10
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
interactive_timeout = 35
join_buffer_size = 2M
key_buffer_size = 192M
local-infile=0
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
log-slow-queries
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=1

max_allowed_packet = 32M
max_connections = 3000
max_heap_table_size = 256M
max_user_connections= 400
max_write_lock_count = 8
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
open_files_limit=128K
query_alloc_block_size = 65536
query_cache_limit = 16M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 262144
range_alloc_block_size = 4096
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
table_cache = 48K
thread_cache_size = 512
tmp_table_size = 256M
transaction_alloc_block_size = 4096
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
wait_timeout = 100
max_connect_errors = 5000

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

How can I fix the problem?

Thank you very much, and sorry for my English.

Comment: sounds to me like the ISP for that server is dropping packets.

Comment: Ping the IP address of your remote host. ping 1.1.1.1 -t

Comment: @KarlosFontana The pings are fine